# "Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy. that was originally added here" con un login en un AsyncTask en Android

Tags: java, android, json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

JSONParser.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

    // constructor
    public JSONParser() {

    }

    public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(final String url) {

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // Construct the client and the HTTP request.
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

            // Execute the POST request and store the response locally.
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            // Extract data from the response.
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            // Open an inputStream with the data content.
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            // Create a BufferedReader to parse through the inputStream.
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            // Declare a string builder to help with the parsing.
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            // Declare a string to store the JSON object data in string form.
            String line = null;

            // Build the string until null.
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }

            // Close the input stream.
            is.close();
            // Convert the string builder data to an actual string.
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // Try to parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // Return the JSON Object.
        return jObj;

    }


    public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                      List params) {

        // Haciendo la Petición HTTP
        try {

            // check for request method
            if(method == "POST"){
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

            }else if(method == "GET"){
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                url += "?" + paramString;
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
            }

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            json = sb.toString();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        // try parse the string to a JSON object
        try {
            jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
        }

        // return JSON String
        return jObj;

    }
}
```

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.org.hewerth.happypets;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private EditText user, pass;
    private Button mSubmit, mRegister;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Clase JSONParser
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();


    // si trabajan de manera local "localhost" :
    // En windows tienen que ir, run CMD > ipconfig
    // buscar su IP
    // y poner de la siguiente manera
    // "http://xxx.xxx.x.x:1234/cas/login.php";

    private static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://login.php";

    // La respuesta del JSON es
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        // setup input fields
        user = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuNick);
        pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usuPass);

        // setup buttons
        mSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.register);

        // register listeners
        mSubmit.setOnClickListener(this);
        mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.login:
                new AttemptLogin().execute();
                break;
            case R.id.register:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, RegistroActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            int success;

            try {
                // Building Parameters
                List params = new ArrayList();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("alias", username));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

                Log.d("request!", "starting");
                // getting product details by making HTTP request
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                        params);

                // check your log for json response
                Log.d("Login attempt", json.toString());

                // json success tag
                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());
                    // save user data
                    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(LoginActivity.this);
                    Editor edit = sp.edit();
                    edit.putString("username", username);
                    edit.commit();

                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ReadComments.class);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(i);
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                } else {
                    Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                    return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;

        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // dismiss the dialog once product deleted
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (file_url != null) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

activity_login.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:background="@drawable/fondo"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="20dip"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/link_to_register"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:fontFamily="cursive"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="HappyPets"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="60sp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usuNick"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Nombre de Usuario"
        android:name="username_textview"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:textAlignment="center" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/usuPass"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
        android:hint="Contraseña"
        android:name="password_textview"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:textAlignment="center" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dip"
        android:paddingRight="15dip"
        android:text="Ingresar"
        android:name="submit"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:paddingLeft="15dip"
        android:paddingRight="15dip"
        android:text="Registrate"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/background_light" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hola Andy, por la estructura de tu clase que es un Activity con un Asynctask que muestra un ProgressDialog, recomiendo uses el segundo método, con eso evitarás que en ocasiones suceda el problema que comentas.

Comment: Tu pregunta sólo incluye código y una captura de pantalla de un error. Una descripción de lo que estás intentando hacer y de dónde ocurre el error sería ideal.

Answer (score 1):

Este error ocurre cuando un dialogo sobrevivie el ciclo de vida de una actividad.

Porqué usas un `ProgressDialog`?

> This class was deprecated in API level O.
>   Use a progress indicator such as ProgressBar inline inside of an activity rather than using this modal dialog.

Se recomienda (con API lvl 0 basicamente desde siempre) de usar un [`ProgressBar`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) en vez de este dialogo, evitando el error mencionado.

Lo colocas en tu `layout`como:

```
 <ProgressBar
     android:id="@+id/progbar"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small"
     android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
```

luego puedes actualizarlo en el código como:

```
int mStatus;
//...
ProgressBar mProgress = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progbar);
mProgress.setProgress(mStatus); // actualizar status
// o relativamente
mProgress.incrementProgressBy(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

El error especificado es:

> **"Activity  has leaked window com.android.internal.policy. that was originally added here"**

Se refiere a que intentas mostrar un Dialogo, en este caso un `ProgressDialog`, cuando la `Activity` que lo inicia no existe o fue destruida.

Esto se puede evitar facilmente llamando el método `dismiss()` del `ProgressDialog`, cuando vamos a background o la `Activity` que abrira el dialogo esta por ser destruida, para eso utilizamos el método `onPause()` :

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if(pDialog != null){
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
    super.onPause();
}
```

> **dismiss()** : Descarta este diálogo, eliminándolo de la pantalla.

---

Otro método es simplemente es evitar mostrarlo cuando enviamos nuestra aplicación a segundo plano o la cerramos, para eso hacemos uso de los métodos `onPause()` y `onResume()`:

```
private static boolean foreground = true; //valida si se permite mostrar el Dialog.


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        foreground = false;
      super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        foreground = true;
      super.onResume();
    }
```

de esta forma podemos saber si mostramos o no el `Dialog` y evitamos el error :

```
  @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (foreground){ //Valida si será mostrado el Dialogo.

          pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
          pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
          pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
          pDialog.setCancelable(true);
          pDialog.show();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Trate de arreglarlo con las dos soluciones posibles, pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error...